# Interesting Stack Overflow data remixes/analyses/visualizations?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, data-dump

What are some interesting Stack Overflow data remixes/analyses/visualizations?

Comment: Are you aware of the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries)?

Answer (score 2):

Kind of old, but there was this [nice video on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lm5-h37VSTc) which used SO's API and Microsoft Labs' Pivot for some nice data analysis

Answer (score 1):

I offered a +500 bounty for people to collaborate on [visualizing SO via code_swarm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75785/anyone-plotting-so-via-code-swarm) a while back, which produced some working code in a variety of flavors. I don't think anyone uploaded a video, but you might be able to make use of something there.