# Bounty autoawarded to an answer that I downvoted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252928/237813), I started a bounty to try to get the bug fixed. Answers were added, and one that I disagreed with and downvoted got the bounty. This is wrong. Don't award bounties to answers I've downvoted.