# When and how can a merged question be deleted?

Tags: support, locked-questions, locked, merged-questions

From [What is a "merged" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158067/843029):

> If the merge stub is *later deleted*, the asker will lose the reputation they earned from it unless it had a score of at least 3 and was visible for at least 60 days (the normal criteria for reputation retention).

Since a merged question is locked and cannot be deleted by the author, then when and how can a merged question be deleted?

Comment: Answer in [this **question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314470/282094), and details in our [deletion FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/282094) (use browser's **F**ind to search for "migrat"). --- If you see your answer there, you can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Rob A _migrated_ question is different from a _merged_ question.

Comment: That is true but the ability to delete the stub isn't going to be different, is it?

Comment: @Rob Not sure, since _"The question is left as a stub, or pathway to the new site, for 30 days, after which it is automatically deleted by a weekly script."_ is directly mentioned in [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/843029), but it's not mentioned in [What is a "merged" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158067/843029).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/migrated-questions/info  https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/merged-questions/info - Case of it happening: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337944/3648282 (without an explanation of "how"). Here [the answer says "flag"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261608/3648282) for the merge, but asking for a deletion is also possible. [Deletion can be voted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262499/3648282) for. --- Since those answers are on a different site (and provide additional methods not in the only answer here) they are not duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 5):

The stub of a merged question can be deleted by an elected or pro-tem moderator, or a staff member.

As an elected and pro-tem moderator I have done this on a few occasions when the stub provides a poor signpost to the question it was merged with. Ideally, the question would have a negative net score and the deletion would be in response to a flag but that might not always be the case.

Comment: It's worth noting that many mods prefer that users not raise flags to ask for merge stubs to be deleted - I had added in this text in the FAQ originally, but an SO mod edited it out claiming it's an invalid use of flags.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I suspect that may be only an SO or largest site mods only preference. We delete few questions and a flag can let us know when there’s something that looks like it needs review. I decline invalid flags but I think these usually look valid.